# change the DHCP lease table with script & sed

Tags: bash, scripts, sed, dhcpd

Dears ,

I have in the dhcp lease file leases , like the following example :

```
lease 192.168.79.15 {
  starts 0 2016/08/21 13:25:45;
  ends 0 2016/08/21 19:25:45;
  cltt 0 2016/08/21 13:25:45;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 8c:1a:bf:11:00:ea;
  uid "\001\214\032\277\021\000\352";
  option agent.circuit-id 0:17;
  option agent.remote-id c0:a8:9:5;
  client-hostname “android-8182e21c852776e7";
```

I need to be able to change the option agent.remote-id fixed values to a string before sending this file somewhere else using , and also if possible to covert circuit-id field to binary from hex . Thinking of the first thing to do , i tried to make a script like follows , but its not working :

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=“/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases”
VAR2=“c0:a8:9:2”
VAR3=“c0:a8:9:3”
VAR4=“c0:a8:9:4”
VAR5=“c0:a8:9:5”
VAR6=“c0:a8:9:6”
VAR7=“c0:a8:9:7”


sed -e ’s/${VAR2}/AOD-ADMIN-OFFICE/g; s/${VAR3}/GOLF-MAINTENANCE-BUILDING/g; s/${VAR4}/MARINA-DRY-STACK/g;s/${VAR5}/DC-SERVICE-ROOM/g;s/${VAR6}/ACPM-ADMIN-OFFICE/g;s/${VAR7}/SEA-WATER-OFFICE/g’ ${VAR1}
```

Comment: it works like this though , 

#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/c0:a8:9:2;/AOD-ADMIN-OFFICE/g; s/c0:a8:9:3;/GOLF-MAINTENANCE-BUILDING/g; s/c0:a8:9:4;/MARINA-DRY-STACK/g;s/c0:a8:9:5/DC-SERVICE-ROOM/g;s/c0:a8:9:6/ACPM-ADMIN-OFFICE/g;s/c0:a8:9:7/SEA-WATER-OFFICE/g'    /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases

but will it works within a script ? Also , how can you associate this along with the circruit id conversion to binary .

Comment: So you want to change the values of `agent.circuit-id` and `agent.remote-id` parameters?

Comment: Your first issue is probably that your variables include non-ascii quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that the strings in your variable assignments use non-ASCII quote characters. Because of that, `sed` is trying to match `“c0:a8:9:2”` instead of `c0:a8:9:2`.

Beyond that, I don't really see the point of defining a whole lot of variables for this; IMHO it would be cleaner to use a *here document* e.g.

```
sed -f- /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases << 'EOF'
s/c0:a8:9:2/AOD-ADMIN-OFFICE/
s/c0:a8:9:3/GOLF-MAINTENANCE-BUILDING/
s/c0:a8:9:4/MARINA-DRY-STACK/
s/c0:a8:9:5/DC-SERVICE-ROOM/
s/c0:a8:9:6/ACPM-ADMIN-OFFICE/
s/c0:a8:9:7/SEA-WATER-OFFICE/
EOF
```

You could instead put the `s/c0:a8:9:2/AOD-ADMIN-OFFICE/` lines in a separate command file, and call it with `sed -f cmdfile /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` if that makes the table easier to maintain, i.e.

In `cmdfile` (or whatever name you choose to call it):

```
# list of agent.remote-id to physical location mappings
# for use in DHCP lease file processing script

s/c0:a8:9:2/AOD-ADMIN-OFFICE/
s/c0:a8:9:3/GOLF-MAINTENANCE-BUILDING/
s/c0:a8:9:4/MARINA-DRY-STACK/
s/c0:a8:9:5/DC-SERVICE-ROOM/
s/c0:a8:9:6/ACPM-ADMIN-OFFICE/
s/c0:a8:9:7/SEA-WATER-OFFICE/
```

then in your script

```
sed -f cmdfile /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

Comment: thanks for that , so i can create the file you provide there as cmdfile ( which extension ) , amd call this in a bash script ? What if i also want to convert the option . Agent id to binary from ascii ? 

The bash file i have , copies the lease file to a different location then tar it and send it via ssh to a remote server . 
What i want to do is before sending this , edit both circuit id and option id in the file  . So can can i call this line 

Sed -f  cmdfile /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases 

In a the bash file ?

Comment: @AboodAlakhras please see my expanded answer - I hope it is clear now

Comment: Also changing agent circuit id to binary ,

Comment: Thanks alot , but what is the cmdfile extension ? I mean what shall be the file .txt or what ? If i also want to convert the circuit id to binay , how we can do this consalidation ? The concept is to send the lease with ips indicating the switch location and the port number . The switch sends remote id as managmrnt ip of the switch and circuit as the port number in hex

Comment: Extensions have no particular significance in this context - see for example [Which extension to use for text files? (Unix/Linux)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/which-extension-to-use-for-text-files-unix-linux). IMHO you should ask about the format conversion in a separate question: be **specific** about exactly what digits you want to convert, and to what (first you said binary, now you are talking about hex). Give a concrete example of how you want the output to look.

Comment: bith circuit ids and remote ids are values in hex . For the remote id i need to change the values to what you advised , since they are fixed values amd refere to a switch location . For the circuit id , its actually a port number , so this value changes depending from where the lease come from . Thank you for solving the issue for remote id , i will try the script . Now am asking , what if i want to change the remote id as above ( the fixed values ) , and convert the circuit id values to binary ( taking into consderation that this is a variable )

Comment: @AboodAlakhras that information **belongs in your original question** - along with a **clear** indication of exactly how you want the result to look (does `0:17` represent a single numerical field? or two? should the output look like `10001` or `0:10001`... or something else?

Comment: I am so sorry for this confusion i caused !  The output 0:17 is actually in hexadecimal , and idicates the port number of a switch ( 1-48 ) , in order for this to be human readable , the output should be in decimal

Comment: For now i added -i to the sed -f in order to write to the file . This is all what i need thanks .